# codeigniter route fixed string or character with wildcard (any)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my codeigniter project i want to use two character with wildcard any

```
$route['(school*)/(:any)'] = 'Schools/static_school/$1/$2';
```

this is not working.

I want to create a  url like `domain.com/schoolTesting/urlofschool`
similarly another record can be

```
domain.com/schoolWorking/urlofschool
```

Comment: No these are two specific example.  I need generic route where school will be followed by any text

Comment: again incorrect. see this example: www.domain.com/school1613001/town-south-school/ . number part is generic it can be any number.

Comment: ok try with this : `$route['school(:num)/(:any)'] = 'Schools/town_south_school/$1';`

Comment: Sorry sir but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$route['school(:num)/(:any)'] = 'Schools/url-of-school/$1';
```

Access `url` should be like this :

```
www.domain.com/school1613001/town-south-school
```

Your `Schools` controller's method should be like this :

```
public function town_south_school()
{
  echo "string";  
}
```